# Integrate Wordnet to C# application

Tags: .net, lucene.net, wordnet, synset

I'm building a c#.Net desktop application that does indexing and searches using Lucene based on a collection that I have. This requires me to get synonyms for certain words. So I want to use Wordnet to get the synonyms of those words. After searching the net for hours, I'm still unable to find how I should approach it.

I require a method from which I can integrate a library such as Synset into my application than installing wordnet because I should have this as a single application. Is there a solution for this? Please direct me to the correct path. There are an API and a database, I prefer the API solution, so if you could point me to the libraries I require to reach the endpoints of Wordnet, it would be really helpful

I'm quite new to Lucene search engines and Wordnet, so I require a method I can comprehend to do

Thanks in Advance